# How to loop over mongodb array with express and monk to create a page for each element?

Tags: node.js, express, monk

I am building a web app with express, nodejs and monk. I am trying to create a page for each element of an array in my mongodb database.

That data is already in the collection called **collections** with the key **coll_list** like so:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53dbaefd3d85d57492506f1f"), "coll_list" : [     "data_pagename1", 
     "data_pagename2", "data_pagename3" ] }
```

I thought it might be possible to loop over all the elements in **coll_list** with something like:

```
 router.get('/index', function(req, res) {
     var db = req.db;
     var collection = db.get('collections');
     collection.find( "coll_list" , function(e,docs) {
       for (elems in docs) {
         res.render(elems, {
           elems : docs
         });
       }
     });
 });
```

Any suggestions or help/pointers on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [req.params](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#req.params)

```
router.get('/coll/:id',
  function(req,res){
     //access the id by req.params.id
     //req.params.id will essentially be the _id of the document
     //use it to obtain data from mongoDB and render the page using that data
     //From the front end you make the call to /coll/<ObjectId> like
     // /coll/53dbaefd3d85d57492506f1f and you get that id in req.params.id and use it to
     //render data specific to that _id. 

  });
```

Thus, using a single route you would be able to create a page for every item in `coll_list`

Comment: Thanks. Your answer wasn't too specific that I didnt learn anything. But not too vague that  I  didn't understand.

Comment: @ColinRiddell sorry if it was too generic. Comment if you need any help.